# How to get the first item from an associative PHP array?

Tags: php

If I had an array like:

```
$array['foo'] = 400;
$array['bar'] = 'xyz';
```

And I wanted to get the first item out of that array without knowing the key for it, how would I do that? Is there a function for this?

Comment: *(reference)* [Arrays](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Array Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Comment: The inverse of this task is to use `end()` or `array_key_last()`: [Return an element from the last array in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7227154/2943403)

Answer (score 373, accepted):

[`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) gives you the first value of the array if you have an element inside the array:

```
$value = reset($array);
```

It also gives you `FALSE` in case the array is empty.

Comment: To note: `$arr = array(/* stuff */); $val = $arr? reset($arr): /* value to indicate array is empty */;`

Comment: More information on the reset function: [www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_reset.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_reset.asp)

Comment: What if i want to get the key and value?

Answer (score 116):

## PHP latest

```
// Leveraging the ?? coalescing operator:
$el = $array[array_key_first($array)] ?? 'Array is empty';
```

## Danger Will Robinson!

Emphasis mine:

> And I wanted to get **the first item** out of that array without knowing the key for it

But what is the *first item*?

With *lists* it is obvious, it is item number 0:

```
 [ 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' ] // Apple it is.
```

`[ 'a' => 'x', 'b' => 'y' ]` is called an *array* in PHP, but is more aptly called a **dictionary** and has no "natural" order. So the code above (and the codes below) will return the "first" key **in order of definition**, but that order might change unintendedly, leading to subtle and difficult-to-track bugs:

```
// [ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 ]
// The first key is "a".
unset($arr['a']);
// [ 'b' => 2 ]
$arr['a'] = 1;
// [ 'b' => 2, 'a' => 1 ]
// The first key is now "b".
```

So, even if it might be a performance killer in some scenarios, you might perhaps be better served by

```
$arr[min(array_keys($arr))] ?? 'Array is empty';
```

or consider whether the "first key" is what you actually want.

## PHP < 7.3

If you don't know enough about the array (you're not sure whether the first key is *foo* or *bar*) then the array might well also be, maybe, **empty**.

So it would be best to check, especially if there is the chance that the returned value might be the boolean FALSE:

```
$value = empty($arr) ? $default : reset($arr);
```

The above code uses `reset` and so **has side effects** (it resets the internal pointer of the array), so you might prefer using `array_slice` to quickly access a copy of the first element of the array:

```
$value = $default;
foreach(array_slice($arr, 0, 1) as $value);
```

---

Assuming you want to get **both the key and the value separately**, you need to add the fourth parameter to `array_slice`:

```
foreach(array_slice($arr, 0, 1, true) as $key => $value);
```

To get the first item **as a pair** (`key => value`):

```
$item = array_slice($arr, 0, 1, true);
```

Simple modification to get the **last** item, key and value separately:

```
foreach(array_slice($arr, -1, 1, true) as $key => $value);
```

## performance

If the array is not really big, you don't actually need `array_slice` and can rather get a copy of the whole keys array, then get the first item:

```
$key = count($arr) ? array_keys($arr)[0] : null;
```

If you have a very big array, though, the call to `array_keys` will require significant time and memory more than `array_slice` (both functions walk the array, but the latter terminates as soon as it has gathered the required number of items - which is one).

A notable exception is when you have the first key which points to a very large and convoluted object. In that case `array_slice` will duplicate that first large object, while `array_keys` will only grab the keys.

## PHP 7.3+

PHP 7.3 onwards implements `array_key_first()` as well as `array_key_last()`. These are explicitly provided to access first and last keys efficiently without resetting the array's internal state as a side effect.

So since PHP 7.3 the first *value* of `$array` may be accessed with

```
$array[array_key_first($array)];
```

You still had better check that the array is not empty though, or you will get an error:

```
$firstKey = array_key_first($array);
if (null === $firstKey) {
    $value = "Array is empty"; // An error should be handled here
} else {
    $value = $array[$firstKey];
}
```

Comment: @AhmedShefeer well, the other answer is not only the *accepted* one but has been there for *eight more years*. I'm sort of picking up the crumbs here :-D . But thanks for the vote of confidence!

Comment: It looks to me like this is the best answer, since the only other non-deprecated one that gives both the key and value is the aborted foreach loop, which is awkward. The other answers give only the value without the key.

Comment: loved this ans, modern approach and updated with time.

Comment: @LSerni Don't know if you are still active , but I was stuck and this well explained and updated post saved me. Thank you

Comment: @izk I'm always active! :-D

Comment: Bump this as the answer. We live in a 7.3+ world nowadays.

Answer (score 54):

Fake loop that breaks on the first iteration:

```
$key = $value = NULL;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    break;
}

echo "$key = $value\n";
```

Or use [`each()`](https://www.php.net/each) (**warning:** [deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php)):

```
reset($array);
list($key, $value) = each($array);

echo "$key = $value\n";
```

Comment: Probably because reset() is simpler.

Comment: Because the solution is in your first line of code but you're continuing writing another completely unneeded line.

Comment: reset wont return the key

Comment: +1 for the 'fake loop'. I've needed to retrieve the first elements key and value, while not going through each element. The `reset()` function would only retrieve the first value.

Comment: +1 for the fake loop as well, I need to kept the key so reset was not an option

Comment: Fake loop! That's a clever little idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

There's a few options. [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) will return the first element, but it will also remove the first element from the array.

```
$first = array_shift($array);
```

[`current()`](http://php.net/current) will return the value of the array that its internal memory pointer is pointing to, which is the first element by default.

```
$first = current($array);
```

If you want to make sure that it is pointing to the first element, you can always use [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset).

```
reset($array);
$first = current($array);
```

Comment: I like this answer as most complete, but note `reset()` actually returns the element, so following that with a `$first = current($array)` is redundant.

Answer (score 18):

another easy and simple way to do it use array_values

```
array_values($array)[0]
```

Comment: `reset()` is a much better option since it returns false if the array is empty. your solution won't work for example in the question

Comment: In PHP 7+ something like this would work: `array_values($array)[0] ?? FALSE`

Answer (score 13):

Just so that we have some other options: `reset($arr);` good enough if you're not trying to keep the array pointer in place, and with very large arrays it incurs an minimal amount of overhead. That said, there are some problems with it:

```
$arr = array(1,2);
current($arr); // 1
next($arr);    // 2
current($arr); // 2
reset($arr);   // 1
current($arr); // 1 !This was 2 before! We've changed the array's pointer.
```

The way to do this without changing the pointer:

```
$arr[reset(array_keys($arr))]; // OR
reset(array_values($arr));
```

The benefit of `$arr[reset(array_keys($arr))];` is that it raises an warning if the array is actually empty.

Comment: very descriptive answer, and it means a lot to others. Thanks man.

Answer (score 6):

Test if the a variable is an array before getting the first element.  When dynamically creating the array if it is set to null you get an error.

For Example:

```
if(is_array($array))
{
  reset($array);
  $first = key($array);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use array_values

```
$firstValue = array_values($array)[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do 
`$first = reset($array);`

Instead of

```
reset($array);
$first = current($array);
```

As `reset()`

returns the first element of the array after reset;

Answer (score 3):

You can make:

```
$values = array_values($array);
echo $values[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

To get first value of the array :-

```
<?php
   $large_array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'hello' => 'world');
   var_dump(current($large_array));
?>
```

To get the first key of the array

```
<?php
   $large_array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'hello' => 'world');
   $large_array_keys = array_keys($large_array);
   var_dump(array_shift($large_array_keys));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use reset() function to get the first item out of that array without knowing the key for it like this.

```html
$value = array('foo' => 400, 'bar' => 'xyz');
echo reset($value);
```

output //
400

Answer (score 2):

Starting with [PHP 7.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) it's possible to do without resetting the internal pointer. You would use `array_key_first`. If you're sure that your array has values it in then you can just do:

```
$first = $array[array_key_first($array)];
```

More likely, you'll want to handle the case where the array is empty:

```
$first = (empty($array)) ? $default : $array[array_key_first($array)];
```

Answer (score 2):

In one line:

```
$array['foo'] = 400;
$array['bar'] = 'xyz';
echo 'First value= ' . $array[array_keys($array)[0]];
```

Expanded:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$key = $keys[0];
$value = $array[$key];
echo 'First value = ' . $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: But be aware the array will have one item removed.

Answer (score 1):

I do this to get the first and last value. This works with more values too.

```
$a = array(
    'foo' => 400,
    'bar' => 'xyz',
);
$first = current($a);   //400
$last = end($a);    //xyz
```

Comment: This only works when the internal pointer is at the first element. While this is good because it doesn't reset the position of the pointer, it only works when the pointer is already rest.