# Return an element from the last array in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, element

How to display an element from the last array dynamically in PHP.
For example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [user_id] => 8 [category_path] => Sport)
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 8 [user_id] => 8 [category_path] => Computers))
```

in order to return the "id" from the last array

```
8
```

And for the next example

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [user_id] => 8 [category_path] => Sport)
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 8 [user_id] => 5 [category_path] => Computers)
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 16 [user_id] => 45 [category_path] => Soft))
```

in order to return

```
   16
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getLastId(&$array){
    $tmp=end($array);
    return $tmp['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about counting the elements and accessing them like this?

```
$array[count($array)-1] # to get the last array item
$array[count($array)-1]['id'] # to get the id of the last entry
```