# PHP: sort alphabetical array so that 'A' is highest and 'Z' is lowest

Tags: php

I have an array that is populated with 4 alphabetical letters from 'A' to 'Z'. I'm trying to find the lowest value where 'Z' is the lowest and 'A' the highest (like a grading system). For example:

`$abc = ['A', 'G', 'Y', 'B'];`

In this case Y is the lowest grade, but obviously `min()` and `max()` won't work since they give me the opposite of what I'm looking for. Is there a way to do it in PHP without writing my own function?

Comment: ...`asort()` = values `ksort()` = keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$m = array('A', 'G', 'Y', 'B');
asort($m);
print_r($m); //outpu: Array ( [0] => A [3] => B [1] => G [2] => Y )
```

Comment: Thanks Chrys and I'L'I, `asort()` got me half way there. I ended up using `array_shift()` and `array_pop()` to get the highest and lowest values.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `array_shift()` and `array_pop()`. Credit to: [Jeremy Ruten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617157/how-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-associative-php-array)

```
$abc = array('A', 'G', 'Y', 'B');
asort($abc);
print_r($abc); // Array ( [0] => A [3] => B [1] => G [2] => Y ) 
$highest = array_shift($abc);
$lowest = array_pop($abc);
echo "Highest: $highest. Lowest: $lowest"; // Highest: A. Lowest: Y
```