# Why reset an array parameter before using it?

Tags: php, arrays, reset

I was reading some Wordpress plugin code when I come across this [function](https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/bp_nouveau_hook/):

```
function bp_nouveau_hook( $pieces = array() ) {
    if ( ! $pieces ) {
        return;
    }
 
    $bp_prefix = reset( $pieces );
    if ( 'bp' !== $bp_prefix ) {
        array_unshift( $pieces, 'bp' );
    }
 
    $hook = join( '_', $pieces );
 
    /**
     * Fires inside the `bp_nouveau_hook()` function.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 3.0.0
     */
    do_action( $hook );
}
```

As far as I understand you use `reset()` when the array's pointer could be changed by functions such as `prev()` or `next()` etc. But by reading this code, I don't see any chance the `$pieces` array parameter's pointer could be changed. Why then use `reset()` here?

Comment: Perhaps to make sure it hasn't been changed before it enters the function?

Comment: If `$pieces` is not a 0-based indexed array, `reset()` is the only reliable way to get the *first* item from the array.

Comment: That's exactly it. The array pointer is copied when passing an array to a function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617157/how-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-associative-php-array/46443841

Comment: image you have an array `['some' => 'value', 'another' => 'one']`, how could you get the first item in this array if you do not know beforehand what the values of the keys are? By using `reset` you will get the first value no matter the keys.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

> Returns the value of the first array element, or false if the array is
> empty.

The reset is done to get the first element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar The array might not have numeric keys. Hence reset is a way to get the first item. That is why it is used here: to get the first item.